# 5 star Bayes Rating return in percentage

Tags: algorithm, bayesian

Im build 5 star rating system.The problem come when user keep rate the photo and eventually the **br** will return more then 100%,how can i make sure it return in percentage and not more than 100%

```
br = ( (avg_num_votes * avg_rating) + (this_num_votes * this_rating) ) / (avg_num_votes + this_num_votes)
```

Comment: consider I build an online photo rating..every user can rate photo with 5 star given scale.By using bayes( above formula) I can get the ranking ,which photo should be on top but can it give in percentage not more than 100 ,that what I try to achieve

Comment: Get the `br` of the top rated picture and do this: `this_br_rate / top_br_rate * 100`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `avg_rating` and `this_rating` are both no more than 100%, and all values are non-negative, your formula will never give more than 100%.

```
br = ( (avg_n * avg_r) + (this_n * this_r) ) / (avg_n + this_n) <=
   <= ( (avg_n * 100%) + (this_n * 100%) ) / (avg_n + this_n) =
   = 100% * (avg_n + this_n) / (avg_n + this_n) =
   = 100%
```

If `avg_rating` and `this_rating` are not measured in percentage (e.g. they are the number of stars 0-5), you should convert them to percentages first.